# Fill up associative array to desired length

Tags: php, arrays

So I have 3 arrays in my code. The first(`$values`) one has some values in it, the second(`$keys`) has corresponding keys for the first array as values and in the third(`$someOtherArray`) one only the length of the array matters not the values.

Example:

```
$values = [343, 90];
$keys =   [  2,  3];
$desiredLength = count($someOtherArray);
```

Now my goal is to create an array with the length of `$someOtherArray`, so `$desiredLength`. The array should contain the `$values` at their corresponding key, which are defined in `$keys`, and the rest of the array should be filled up to the length of `$desiredLength` with a default value, here I want 0.

So if my desired length is 5 my expected result would be:

```
Array (
    [0] => 0,
    [1] => 0,
    [2] => 343,
    [3] => 90,
    [4] => 0
)
```

This is my code so far:

```
function create_array($someOtherArray, $values, $keys)
{
    $result = [];
    $length = sizeof($values);
    $comma_separated_values = implode(",", $values);

    for($i = 0; $i <= $someOtherArray - 1; $i++)
    {
        #Code...
        array_splice($result, $comma_separated_values, $values);
    }

    return $result;

}
```

Right now this code isn't working and it shows me an error:

> array_splice() expects parameter 3 to be a long, array given in

Comment: And with what value should be the array filled if you only have 2 values and you want an array with a length of 9?

Comment: Please provide full code including those 3 arrays.

Comment: *array which will have the length equal to company_time array and has the values 343 and 90 on indexes 2,3* - show how should look the expected array's data

Comment: @Rizier123 i want to pass this array as a data in chart.js other values should be zero

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sir see the edited question please

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad Okay, then you probably want to open up the manual and take a look at `array_fill()` to fill up an array with your desired length and the default value, `array_replace()` to replace the default values with the values you know, and `array_combine()` because you want the keys and values you know to be combined, before you replace them.

Comment: @Rizier123 ok sir can u help me in ameliorating the code

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad I can help you if you tried something and you got stuck. But I won't if you just want me to write you code.

Comment: @Rizier123 no sir i have created the array using array fill n placed zeros on all the indexes

Comment: @Rizier123 now what should i do

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad Good. Already 1/3 done. Now you want to combine your values(`$time_to_minutes`) and keys(`$index`) together, so that you get an associative array and see your key/value pairs if you do `print_r($combinedArray);`.

Comment: ok @Rizier123 let me try that

Comment: @Rizier123 my index array is having 2,3 as a value the keys are [0]=>2,[1]=>3 i want 2,3 not 0and 1

Comment: if other values are 0, then you can simply assign 9 values and then can replace index 2 and 3 with the required value or these position  may vary?

Comment: @Rizier123 thanku for editing my question i m new to stackoverfollow thats whi i dont know how to adequately elucidate the question

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad So what do you have already? You filled up an array with your desired length and the default value 0 with `array_fill()` right? Now you also used `array_combine()` to combine your keys and values together into one array? If yes then the last step is to just use `array_replace()` and say that you want to replace the key/value pairs from the `array_fill`'ed array with the values from the `array_combine`'d array.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use several PHP array functions.

```
$values = [343, 90];
$keys = [2, 3];
$desiredLength = 5;

$existingValues = array_combine($keys, $values);

$result = array_fill(0, $desiredLength, 0);
$result = $existingValues + $result;

ksort($result);

print_r($result);
```

#### Explanation

First, we create an array where the keys are taken from the `$keys` array, and the values are from `$values` with [array_combine](https://secure.php.net/array_combine):

```
$existingValues = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Then create a structure for the resulting array, where fill all the values with `0`. This is done with [array_fill](https://secure.php.net/array_fill):

```
$result = array_fill(0, $desiredLength, 0);
```

Now, we need to merge the arrays, so that if they have the same indexes, then values are overwritten. This is done with `+` operator, but the order of arrays is *important*! They way we do it, the resulting array will keep the indexes from the `$existingValues`:

```
$result = $existingValues + $result;
```

Also, we cannot do it with [array_merge](https://secure.php.net/array_merge), because it doesn't override numerics keys:

> If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Finally, sort the array by keys:

```
ksort($result);
```

Comment: Very nice answer! Also showing what values are in the array in each step can make it easier to follow and see what is going on (E.g. `existingValues` looks now like this: `[2 => 343, 3 => 90]`). Also a little detail: If you look in OP's question he wants the array key/values to be in order, so `+` won't work here (Look at the keys of OP's expected output and yours), but you can change `+` with `array_replace()` and it all works fine :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about sorting, I added `ksort` to the answer.

Comment: Sir why this code is giving me error that array_combine expects parameter 1 to be array,null given in

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad This means, as the error message says, that you don't have an array in your `$keys`. What do you get with `var_dump($keys);`?

Comment: @Rizier123 i get array(2){ [0]=>int(2) [1]=>int(3) }

Comment: @Rizier123 what does it mean

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad So your error message you say you get and the output shown from the variable don't match. This means you don't tell us something. Shows us your code with the example data and how you use the code from the answer.

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad Use a pastebin or some online IDE! Since the code is quite big, don't post it in the comments.

Comment: @Rizier123 kindly help me

Comment: @MasoomaAhmad There is still undefined and unknown stuff in your code. Look at this answer, read it carefully, and the try to apply it to your code. (Hint: In `check_if_exists()` you return NULL, if you don't enter the if statement)